# Imported a jar file into Android Studio but it still can't resolve my class?

Tags: android, jar, symbols, resolve

I've spent all day working on this and now I'm at the point where I've read everything about importing jar files and it still isn't working.

I'm trying to import a class from a project I've done in Eclipse. The class is called Message and it's in my Eclipse project ChatClient. So I made a jar file of ChatClient and did the following:

I copied the jar file into libs.

I've added it to Dependencies in project structure.

I have the line " compile files('src/main/libs/ChatClient.jar')" in my build.gradle file which is all good.

When I clean my project I have no errors.

When I rebuild my project I get "error: cannot find symbol class Message".

I tried "file" then "invalidate Caches/Restart" but when it restarts all my lines of code with 'Message' are still underlined in red.

I don't know if this has anything to do with it but I also get this error:
ClassFormatError: Method "" in class com/intellij/util/TimeoutUtil has illegal signature "(\java/lang/String;)V": Method "" in class com/intellij/util/TimeoutUtil has illegal signature "(\java/lang/String;)V"

but I have no idea what that's talking about.

Thanks for any help.

Oh, and the program works fine if I copy the Message.java file in, but then the server doesn't like it because it can't recognize the class when it's converted to bytes from a different package. I think that's because of the serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'd stupidly exported the jar file when my Message class wasn't in a package. Putting it into a package com.example.name and then exporting it fixed the problem.

I can't believe how long I spent on this!